# Fieldset compatability with IE11

Tags: angular, internet-explorer-11, fieldset

I have used fieldset in angular 8, it works fine with google chrome but in IE11 the code after search breaks at fieldset does not behave properly and values show over placeholder but after some time the defect improves on its own. Do I have to add some import or edit fieldset tag for proper functioning in IE11?

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

Comment: Do you mean after enter value into the textbox, the placeholder not disappear?Can you post the related code (include the html code and CSS style, if it contains javascript code, please also post the related script) to reproduce the problem? From [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/fieldset), the `<fieldset>` tag support IE browser

Comment: thanks for the answer, actually was using placeholder and mat-label both in same field due to which it was happening

Comment: Can you post the related code to reproduce the problem in a [stackblitz sample](https://stackblitz.com/)? I have checked the Form field with label sample from [this link](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview), it seems that everything works well in IE browser. You could check it.